# supremum and infimum of a bounded and decreasing sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions

Is there supremum and infimum of a bounded sequence? I have a bounded and decreasing sequence. Why does this sequence have infimum?

Comment: This is a fundamental analytic property of the real numbers: any bounded increasing sequence converges. Similarly, any bounded decreasing sequence converges. Does every convergent sequence have an infimum?

Comment: And even more, the set of values of a bounded sequence is bounded, so it has infimum and supremum regardless of the monotonicity of the sequence.

Comment: Any bounded *set* in $\mathbb{R}$ has a supremum/infimum. This is the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-upper-bound_property

Answer (score 1):

The [Axiom of Completeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers) states that every bounded set of real numbers has a least upper bound, a supremum. Notice the word axiom. Notice further that the AOC says nothing about the existence of infima. Why? Because we can prove the existence of an infimum using the AOC.